# How to update keys in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `{}` with a `string -> list` relationship, like:

```
'Something.Default.' : ['a=initiator', 'b=00:00:00']
'Something.Session.' : ['b=acceptor', 'c=7039']
```

I'd like to change keys to drop the last `.` `'Something.Default.'` should become `'Something.Default'`.

This is obviously wrong, but it illustrates what I am looking for

```
for key in my_dictionary:
    key = key[:-1]
```

How can I iterate over each key and change it?

Comment: Are those keys strings, such as "Something.Default."?

Comment: Can you not fix the source of the data before you build the dictionary?

Comment: Ok, whoever down-voted me - care to say why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not change a mutable object such as a list or dictionary while iterating over its contents, so you are best of creating a new dictionary modifying the relevant keys where necessary.  This uses a ternary to truncate the key by one character if it ends in a period ('.'), otherwise use the original key.

```
my_dictionary = {key[:-1] if key[-1] == '.' else key: value
                 for key, value in my_dictionary.iteritems()}  # Python 2
```

The new dictionary is reassigned to the old variable name `my_dictionary`.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a new dictionary with the modifications.

```
orig_dict = {'foox': 'bar', 'bazx': 'bat'}
new_dict = {key[:-1]: value for key, value in orig_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

get each key , make new key with last `.` removed, then transfer data and delete that dict.

```
for info in dict:
  if info[-1]=='.':
    dict[info[:-1]] = dict[info]
    del dict[info]
```

Answer (score 0):

Morgan Thrapp's answer was bang on. but here's a little modification

```
orig_dict = {key[:-1]: value for key, value in orig_dict.items()}
```

You don't need to create a new dict object. Just a minor clean up job.

Comment: This should just be a comment to his answer.

Comment: That's true. I just did it that way to break down the steps to make it clearer for readers.

Comment: unfortunately i don't have enough reputation to comment. Making my way to the top

Comment: This *does* create a new dict object. It just replaces the original instead of using a new variable.